# How to create a multi row and column by given images in html, css only

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new in this field. I am trying to create the multi row and column with responsive design. Without using any js. Inside this image every field has a image. click [here](https://ibb.co/f9sQp6H) to check the modal of screen.

I had tried with **html**

```
      <div className="photoGallery">
        <div className="col">
          <img src={1} alt="this is minion" />
          <img src={2} alt="" />
        </div>

        <div className="col">
          <img src={4} alt="" />
          <img src={7} alt="" />
          <img src={4} alt="" />
        </div>

        <div className="col">
          <img src={4} alt="" />
          <img src={4} alt="" />
          <img src={7} alt="" />
        </div>

        <div className="col">
          <img src={7} alt="" />
          <img src={4} alt="" />
          <img src={2} alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

and **css**

```
.photo-gallery {
  margin-top: 5rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 3rem !important;
}

.photo-gallery .head {
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: solid #919191;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .title {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}

.title-text {
  /* height: 35px; */
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 62%;
}

.photoGallery {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.photoGallery .col {
  -webkit-box-flex: 24%;
  -ms-flex: 24%;
  flex: 24%;
  max-width: 24%;
  padding: 0.25%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .photoGallery .col {
    -webkit-box-flex: 49%;
    -ms-flex: 49%;
    flex: 49%;
    max-width: 49%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .photoGallery .col {
    -webkit-box-flex: 99%;
    -ms-flex: 99%;
    flex: 99%;
    max-width: 99%;
  }
}

.photoGallery .col img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.5% 0;
  @media (max-width: 599px) {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
}
}
```

But not able to create click [here](https://ibb.co/cQsck2z).Any suggestion will help me a lot.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can see in google chrome explorer when you add `display: flex;` property, this menu :
 [image]

I think this is the best way for you to learn how to use flexbox properties.

You can also press the "flex" button in the item category of your developer mode to see the delimitation of each sub div of your main div with the `display flex` property :

[image]

[image]